# pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, connection, pymongo

I tested a python program connecting to MongoDB, with the DB driver called pymongo, but received the following errors.

The related envirement:

- MongoDB: version = 2.6.1
- Python: version = 2.7.9
- pymongo: version = 2.8

And, the error is:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> conn = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 241, in __init__
    max_pool_size, document_class, tz_aware, _connect, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 377, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Is `mongod` running and accepting anonymous connections?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to connect as root user into the terminal using the cmd :
"sudo mongod" and be sure that your folder /data/db does not have any restriction for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, since the Mongo Daemon failed to start and isn't listening you get the connection error.
You can try following steps:

1. MongoDB make /data/db as the default data directory.
2. You should start MongoDB by **mongod** command.

   ```
   ~ » mongod

   mongod --help for help and startup options
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.041+0800 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7543 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=simbazz
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.042+0800 [initandlisten]
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.042+0800 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.042+0800 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.1
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.042+0800 [initandlisten] git version: 4b95b086d2374bdcfcdf2249272fb552c9c726e8
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.042+0800 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin mci-osx108-6.build.10gen.cc 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.042+0800 [initandlisten] allocator: system
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.042+0800 [initandlisten] options: {}
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.042+0800 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.042+0800 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
   2015-05-17T11:42:54.635+0800 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
   ```
3. retry to connect to MongoDB by pymongo driver. (in python shell)

   ```
   >>> conn = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)
   >>>
   ```
4. MongoDB prints log information on shell window like this:

   ```
   2015-05-17T11:43:40.514+0800 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60862 #1 (1 connection now open)
   2015-05-17T11:43:54.209+0800 [PeriodicTaskRunner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 28ms
   2015-05-17T11:43:54.214+0800 [PeriodicTaskRunner] task: WriteBackManager::cleaner took: 5ms
   2015-05-17T11:43:54.221+0800 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:33 virt:2654
   2015-05-17T11:43:54.221+0800 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
   2015-05-17T11:43:54.221+0800 [clientcursormon]  connections:1
   ```

Hope to help you :)